Why is the CLIP model sometimes referred to by the name of its image encoder only (e.g., ViT-B/32)?
I've noticed that in some discussions, the CLIP model is referred to by the name of its image encoder only, such as "ViT-B/32." However, CLIP consists of both an image encoder and a text encoder. Why do community use the name of the image encoder to refer to the entire CLIP model in some contexts? Is there a specific reason for this practice?
